# screen overlay detected when my app loads

Tags: android

I am getting complaints from my customers that when they load my app, they see a "Screen Overlay Detected" alert message from the system.  Note that this only occurs on Android M or higher.

The alert looks something similar to below.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEGzf.png

From my understanding, this is caused because some "other" app on the device is requesting the "overlay" permission.  I've confirmed with my customers that if they remove the app that has the "overlay" permission, then it fixes the problem but is there anything I can do on my side?

Meaning, is there some way for me to inform the system to not allow this alert dialog to be displayed?  It's distracting to my customers to see this every time they load my app and it's more frustrating to "me" that there is nothing I can do to fix this.

Comment: I believe this will pop up if your app is requesting a permission while an overlay app is active. Android does not allow this since it is possible for the overlay app to interact with the screen. There isn't anything you can do from your side besides not requesting the permission (which isn't really an option I'm sure).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using a Screen Filtering app(the brownish overlay on the screen). Turn off and it won't bug you.[1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126798/screen-overlay-detected-dialog)

Comment: Reread the question please and either modify your answer or remove it.